# How to create folder (daily, monthly) backup S3 laravel when using spatie backup?

Tags: laravel, backup, laravel-backup

I use laravel v5.5 and use spatie backup v5 (https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-backup/v5/introduction).
function backup is success. but when I check to S3, the path folder is **myBackup/2018-04-29-01-00-07.zip.**

I want the backup path is :
myBackup/**daily**/2018-04-29-01-00-07.zip.
myBackup/**monthly**/2018-05-29-01-00-07.zip.

is it possible ?

Comment: Have you asked in the issue tracker first?

Comment: @Kyslik not yet.

Comment: Try that first, you will get the right exposure, here you have less chance that someone uses the package + knows its background.

Comment: @Kyslik thanks I will..